# Multi-valued data in DynamoDB using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

After scouring the documentation and various tutorials, I cannot figure out how to set or update an attribute on a dynamo Item that is a multi-valued data type (number or string set). I'm using boto (boto.dynamodb2, to be specific -- not boto.dynamodb).

Trying something like this (where 'id' is the hash key):

```
Item(Table('test'), data={'id': '123', 'content': 'test', 'list': [1,2,3,4]}).save()
```

Results in this error:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type "<type 'list'>" for value "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

I feel like this must be possible in boto.dynamodb2, but it's odd that I can't find any examples of people doing this. (Everyone is just setting number or string attributes, not number set or string set attributes.)

Any insight on this topic and how I might get this to work with boto would be very much appreciated! I'm guessing I'm overlooking something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, we were able to figure this out on our own. The problem with my example above is that I'm using a list instead of a set. The value of a multi-value attribute MUST be a set.

For example, this works:

```
Item(Table('test'), data={'id': '123', 'content': 'test', 'list': set([1,2,3,4])}).save()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Unfortunately, this limits the use of multi-valued attributes in DynamoDB, since set() cannot have the same value multiple times. This is okay for things like tags, but it's not for lists of arbitrary numeric values.

Comment: Quick questions: do you know if 1) is it possible to have other types than lists cast as sets (for ex: a dict/map) 2) to have nested values, assuming #1 is feasible? According to [this](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2014/10/document-model-dynamodb.html) it should be possible to have a list of dicts, but we cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1):

DnyamoDB now supports Dict/List directly.  Boto doesn't have support for it yet, but it's a small patch until it's supported in production.

```
############################################################
# Patch Dynamizer to support dict/list
############################################################
from boto.dynamodb.types import Dynamizer, get_dynamodb_type

def _get_dynamodb_type(self, attr):
  if isinstance(attr, dict):
    return 'M'
  if isinstance(attr, list):
    return 'L'
  return get_dynamodb_type(attr)

def _encode_m(self, attr):
  result = {}
  for k, v in attr.items():
    result[k] = self.encode(v)
  return result

def _decode_m(self, attr):
  result = {}
  for k, v in attr.items():
    result[k] = self.decode(v)
  return result

def _encode_l(self, attr):
  return [self.encode(v) for v in attr]

def _decode_l(self, attr):
  return [self.decode(v) for v in attr]

Dynamizer._get_dynamodb_type = _get_dynamodb_type
Dynamizer._encode_m = _encode_m
Dynamizer._decode_m = _decode_m
Dynamizer._encode_l = _encode_l
Dynamizer._decode_l = _decode_l
############################################################
# End patch Dynamizer to support dict/list
############################################################
```

Comment: This is more or less in boto now.

Comment: Gary Linscott: Do you know if at present (Apr. 2015) Boto supports the dynamodb `map` datatype and more generally, storing a JSON document as the value of an attribute of an item? Where to find information on this?

Comment: Boto v2.35.2 now supports `map` and `list`. https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2737  I haven't been able to find great docs though...

Answer (score 0):

This works normally with [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html):

```
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)

dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('table')

list = ['1','2','3'] 

table.put_item(
    Item={
        'id': 01,
        'message': list,
        'timestamp': '2019-05-01 22:14:00'
    }
)
```

Your data will be saved like the following:

[image]